# Navbar not collapsing with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that is made with Twitter Bootstrap. On a large screen the navbar is looking nice as it should be but if you see the same navbar on a cellphone the navbar won't collapse.

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="masthead">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/" class="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="goud-zilver.html">Oud goud en zilver</a></li>
            <li><a href="koersen.html">Officiële koersen</a></li>
            <li><a href="webshop/" target="_blank">Webwinkel</a></li>
            <li><a href="diversen.html">Diversen</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
  </div>
```

On the third class i also tried to use nav-collapse but then it is also collapsed on a large screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes follow the instructions [from Betty St](https://stackoverflow.com/users/595152/betty-st) (include responsive css, bootstrap-collapse.js and the Transitions plugin **update: (bootstrap-transition.js) and jQuery)**. You need to add a button / link which triggers the collapse. This tags get the attributes: data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" where data-target can be any css selector. Put your nav between the tag selected under data-target, see: http://bootply.com/62921

**html**:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="masthead">
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>

          <div class="nav-collapse">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="/" class="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="goud-zilver.html">Oud goud en zilver</a></li>
                <li><a href="koersen.html">Officiële koersen</a></li>
                <li><a href="webshop/" target="_blank">Webwinkel</a></li>
                <li><a href="diversen.html">Diversen</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
              </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar -->
      </div>
</div>
```

**update**
Your code is missing the Transitions plugin (bootstrap-transition.js) required by the Collapse plugin. More important you didn't include jQuery.
Now it should work see: http://plnkr.co/l66QqCftGNsaG0xkBrUf

javascript includes:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
```

Note: Consider to include the compiled (or minified) version of the complete javascripts:

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You also need to change the style after collapsing:

```
.navbar .in .nav li {
   display: block;
   float: none;
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I used this code now with the 2 files includes from the first respons. Now the navbar is collapsing fine but if i press the button it doesn't to a thing.

Comment: the bootply works. Can you some the complete code? May be there is a javascript error else on the page

Comment: Ok, here is the complete code of the page:

view-source:http://goud-diamantbank.info/contact.php

paste in browser with 'view-source' included.

Comment: When trying to reduce site loading times, I accidentally removed the required bootstrap dependencies for the collapsing navbar. it seems that using an online minifier caused this problem ...

Answer (score 7):

I had the similar kind of problem. I was totally confused of why my navigation bar is not collapsing in mobile phone. Atlast I found that I missed the following meta tag.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=false;">`

This will solve the problem.

Comment: Bloody hell! This worked for me. It had me stumped for a couple of days to be honest. A nice clean solution. Would you shed more light on why this works or point me to some documentation? No pressure.

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

you need to include the responsive css file of twitter bootstrap, and also use the bootstrap-collapse.js.

Note the info on http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar at 'responsive navbar':

Heads up! The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin and responsive Bootstrap CSS file.

**Quicklinks:**

- css: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css
- js: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need to have the **[compiled version](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)** of bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js with *collapse* and *transition* checked[and therefore included] for compilation.
2. Give your **parent div** an `id`. If it already has one, take note of it. Your parent div is going to be the one whose immediate children comprise the dropdown [the links, buttons, etc.]
3. Add  `data-toggle` and `data-target` to each of the **child elements** of our previously talked-about **parent div**.
   Assuming the **parent div's** is `id="my_parent_div"`, the **child elements** should each have  `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my_parent_div"` appended inside the  link attribute.

Here's a sample from my fixed navbar code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#book"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">Book a Room!</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#services" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#packages" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">Packages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contacts" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">Location</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried this and it broke the nav completely in Angular 4,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I found that i was loading jQuery twice, and I was loading jQuery in the footer, AFTER bootstrap. Everything else worked on the page except for the collapse for some reason. I went back to basics, and it solved the issue. Load jQuery, then bootstrap, and make sure there's no other random includes pages that are loading jQuery as well. 
This relates to bootstrap 4 nav elements.

Comment: Moving jQuery before bootstrap worked for me. It makes sense since bootstrap is using jQuery.

Comment: In my case I was loading *bootstrap.min.js* twice

Answer (score 0):

To add to dustbuster, I also had the issue and tried to load the JQuery first then the Boostrap but the issue didn't get resolved and noted another hint from the link below: -

https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/solved-my-bootstrap-navbar-toggle-is-not-toggling/15222/20

To add the Bootstrap.min.js instead of Bootstrap.min.css. Please do not remove the Bootstrap.min.css when adding the js. Once both added, the issue was resolved.