# Bootstrap navbar collapse isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

Good day for everyone, I will try to use today Twitter bootstrap. And add the default navbar into my page, just copy/paste from **[HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)** When I change browser size it show me the button but when I try to click on it nothing happen, my navbar isn't slide. My project is asp.net mvc4. Download bootstrap via nuget packages, version 3.0. Styles and scripts from bootstrap added into my page.

Anybody have the same problem?

**Nav bar code**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="~/Content/Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Main</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Edit: R# marked navbar-ex1-collapse inside div and told that this class didn't exist

Comment: can u show ur nav bar code

Comment: Possible duplicate of this post pls check out..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885180/navbar-not-collapsing-with-bootstrap

Comment: The markup seems correct, make sure the boostrap.js file is being correctly loaded

Comment: @codebreaker his example based on 2.3 version, my based on 3.0

Comment: @koala_dev triple time I was redownload my markup and the same. Just try  to download from official site

Comment: Thank you guys, just change .min.js to normal .js and everything work fine

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between the min.js and the normal .js, something else must have been going on, at least it's solved now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a **[fiddle](http://bootply.com/81168)** for you, its working fine when change the screen size as well,am using the same code which you are using.

Comment: Yes, just need to change from .min to normal js file, thank you